# Can I count identical tuples of strings in my list?

Tags: python

I have generated a list of tuples from a separate code to show which pairs of numbers converge (in certain equations) given different combinations of variables. I need a way to count how many of each sequence or tuple there are here in my list.  Because of the way I generated the variables to begin with, the tuples are strings.

If ('1','3') is in the list 8 times, I would want to be able to return ('1''3') and the count.

```
converge_list=[('1', '3'), ('1', '7'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '5'), ('7', '9'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '7'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '5'), ('7', '9'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '7'), ('1', '9'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '9'), ('5', '9'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '7'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '5'), ('7', '9'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '5'), ('1', '7'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '5'), ('3', '9'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '7'), ('1', '9'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '9'), ('5', '9'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '7'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '7'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '7'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '5'), ('3', '9'), ('7', '9'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '7'), ('1', '9'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '5'), ('3', '9'), ('7', '9'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '5'), ('1', '7'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '5'), ('3', '9')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient solution.

```
for element in set(converge_list):
    print(element, converge_list.count(element))
```

Comment: thank you, I don't have enough rep points to upvote, but this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score -2):

You can convert the tuples to strings by `str(tuple)` function and count each of them using dictionary.

Comment: Please read [answer] and try to answer questions directly.